# Bootstrap not working in newly created page MVC C#

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to send some mails from my website.
I've made a template, a cshtml page, I want to use bootstrap for styling. I use bootstrap in the whole project. But the problem is, the styling is not working.

I use this in some views and I put this in this template:

```
 @model OnlineCarStore.Models.PurchaseVM
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

 <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

<p>Thanks for the order!</p>
<p>Details: </p>

<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Order details</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <p>No: </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <p> @Model.Id</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <p>Date: </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <p> @Model.Date.ToShortDateString()</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the other page the bootstrap is working well, the styling works. But in this page, the styling it's not working. All the details from order appears, but without any styling. It should appear like this:

[image]

[image]

Can you please advise what to, in order to make the bootstrap work in this page, too.

Comment: how it's appearing.?

Comment: Are you sure that order of calling JS and CSS files in both pages is same.? If not then make it same. Because it happens many times with me too that I changes order of placing `<link> and <script>` tags in wrong order.

Comment: Check your paths .

Comment: I've updated the question. I added a screenshot about how appears. But, I will check what you have suggested

Comment: I've tried that you have suggested, but still not ok. I've tried with this:  @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrapcss")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap"). In the BundleConfig I have: bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/bootstrapcss").Include(
                       "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                       "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css"));
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap").Include(
                                 "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                                 "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css"));, but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If styles in your sent email not work, write inline styles. Because when you send email only inline styles work.

Answer (score 0):

You have this reference to bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.2

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

but do not include the mathcing bootstrap.js

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

you then also have this reference for bootstrap 3.0.0-rc1:

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and two jquery references:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

you should choose either bootstrap 3 or 4, and not have both. Whichever you choose will need a single css, and a single js reference.

Similarly, you should only have one reference to jquery itself.

Comment: I've tried this way, too, and still don't work: (the paths are correct)<head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    </head>
<body>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <p class="label-info">Thanks for the order!</p>

Comment: If you were expecting 'Thanks for the order!' to appear in white text on a blue background, you should add both the `label` and `label-info` class.